# ¿Cómo podría encontrar una palabra dentro de un archivo .txt usando PHP?

Tags: php

Por ejemplo si tengo un archivo.txt con:

```
Hola buenos días, texto
Más texto, adiós, etc
```

Me gustaría poder encontrar por ejemplo la palabra `buenos`
Tan solo saber si tiene esa palabra
¡Gracias por cualquier respuesta!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Lo que podrías hacer es obtener los datos de tu archivo de texto a traves de la función [file_get_contents()](https://secure.php.net/manual/es/function.file-get-contents.php); y luego buscar en ese contenido la palabra que quieras con la función [strpos()](https://secure.php.net/manual/es/function.file-get-contents.php); que comprueba la primera aparición de la cadena buscada, a continuación un ejemplo:

```
<?php
$pagina = file_get_contents('http://humanstxt.org/humans.txt');
$findme = "Flores";
$pos = strpos($pagina, $findme);

// Nótese el uso de ===. Puesto que == simple no funcionará como se espera
if ($pos === false) {
    echo "La cadena '$findme' no fue encontrada en la cadena dada";
} else {
    echo "La cadena '$findme' fue encontrada en la cadena dada";
    echo " y existe en la posición $pos";
}

?>
```

La URL en la función `file_get_contents` lo puedes remplazar con una dirección local a tu archivo de texto, por ejemplo `/tmp/log.txt`

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu ayuda Juan, funciona a la perfección!

Answer (score 2):

Otra manera de hacerlo es usando `file()` y `preg_match()` (expresiones regulares); En escencia es lo mismo, primero descargas la información desde el archivo a una variable u objeto (llevarla a memoria) una vez ahí realizar la busqueda con las operaciones sobre cadenas de caracteres que dispone `php`, yo lo haría así:

```
<?php

$asunto = 'buenos';
/* 
   Las siguientes dos lineas hacen lo mismo que
   file_get_contents() es solo otra manera de hacerlo
*/ 
$rawContent = file("/path/to/file/archivo.txt"); //O usa una URL
$content = implode(" ",$rawContent);//Ya tenemos la cadena en memoria

//Se realiza la búsqueda usando expresiones regulares.
if (preg_match("/$asunto/",$content,$arrMatches)){

    echo "La cadena: ".$asunto." si se encuentra en el archivo";
}
else{

    echo "La cadena: ".$asunto." no se encuentra en la cadena";
}
```

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu aportación Mauricio! Te lo agradezco!