# ¿Cómo puedo buscar resultados similares desde un archivo txt con php?

Tags: php, text

Ya vi este enlace: [¿Cómo podría encontrar una palabra dentro de un archivo .txt usando PHP?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/33923/c%C3%B3mo-podr%C3%ADa-encontrar-una-palabra-dentro-de-un-archivo-txt-usando-php)

Pero lo que quiero hacer es que desde un enlace .txt o un archivo .txt buscar todas las coincidencias posibles sin yo introducir una carácter o número para que busque una coincidencia con el mismo, básicamente quiero buscar todas las coincidencias con todo el contenido que hay en el archivo .txt. Y si no es posible con php, ¿Hay otra forma de hacerlo ya sea con otro lenguaje o algo así?

Comment: Puedes aportar algo, como un archivo txt de ejemplo? Como tal, encontrar todas las coincidencias de algo sin saber que buscas... Es un poco raro no?

Comment: Quiero saber las coincidencias que hay en este archivo: https://www.unitru.edu.pe/Publicaciones/Admision/2020/Res_Ord020IA_generales.txt

Comment: Se que es raro, pero quiero ver los puntajes similares de cada alumno

Comment: Una buena opcion con PHP es leer el archivo estructurar los datos y almacenarlos en una base de datos (mysql puede ser) y luego sobre los datos almacenados puedes hacer todos los querys que quieras.